# Avoid button height expanding due to other button's height expansion in cell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a custom XIB in which I have two buttons which I have pinned to the left and right edges and have added constrains to top, left and bottom for leftButton(named First Button) and top, right and bottom for rightButton(named Second Button)

[image]

Now my problem arises when I add padding to the **right button(Second Button) only**.

Since the left one have top and bottom constraints and adding padding to the right increases the contentSize of the view , so does the leftButton size as well

[image]

I checked the height of both the buttons inside the "Debug View Hierarchy" and both are different (left one being smaller and right one being bigger)

[image]

**What I want to achieve :** Increase the height of the rightButton(Second Button) but keep the height of the leftButton(First Button) as is

**What I have tried so far :**

For leftButton( First Button )

- I tried changing the "Content Hugging Vertical" priority but it does not makes a difference
- Reduced the top and bottom constraint's priority from 1000 to 999 so that maybe the height (which is smaller as showing in the debug view hierarchy) will be given the preference

**EDIT**

Leading margin `>=10` failure

[image]

Comment: Try with **horizontal Content hugging priority**. if you want to increase size of your left button then mark it's priority from 251 t0 250.

Comment: How would _horizontal Content hugging priority_ help? And I don't want to increase the size of left button , I want to do the opposite - Right button's height should increase and left button's height should not be increased

Comment: Will you always be changing the height of *only* the right button? Or do you need the option of changing the height of either button, keeping the non-changed button at its original height?

Comment: @DonMag I want the second case . However it can be the case that left can have 20 padding and right can have 10 padding instead of just right or left alone changing . I mean both can change but the lesser height should not adapt to the greater height but should stick to it's own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Left Button

  - constrain Leading to superview
  - constrain CenterY to superview
  - constrain Top and Bottom to `>=` desired value
- Right Button

  - constrain Trailing to superview
  - constrain CenterY to superview
  - constrain Top and Bottom to `>=` desired value

---

**EDIT**

To explain your follow-up question...

Changing leftButton leading from `= 10` to `>= 10` does not satisfy auto-layout:

[image]

Do you want it to be 10? 11? 20? Auto-layout only sees that you want it `>= 10`.

If you add a constraint between the buttons:

[image]

Now we're telling auto-layout: keep 60-pts between the buttons, and at least 10-pts leading for the left button.

When the right button title gets a little longer:

[image]

Auto-layout "pushes" the left button to the left, keeping 60-pts between them.

If we run out of room:

[image]

Auto-layout still keeps 60-pts between the buttons - by moving left button to the left - but maintains ***at least*** (`>=`) 10-pts leading.

As you see, though, this will require one of the buttons to compress... so you'll need to give one button a higher `Content Compression Resistance Priority` than the other so auto-layout knows which one you want to compress.

Comment: When i try to add **left margin** to the leftButton and add `leading >= 10` to the left button , i get an error _Inequality Constraint ambiguity_ . Can you help me out with this one ?

Comment: @user121095 - hmm... not quite clear what you are doing. What do you mean by ***"left margin"***?

Comment: _leftMargin_ means the left button's leading space

Comment: @user121095 - are you giving left button a Leading constraint of, say, 8, and then *also* giving it a Leading constraint of `>= 10`?

Comment: No. Just `>=10`

Comment: I have updated the question and added an image, please check

Comment: @user121095 - OK... You have no Trailing constraint on `leftButton`, so auto-layout doesn't know what you want to do. If, for example, you also added a constraint of, say, `100`, between the buttons, auto-layout would be happy. It would allow *more* than 10-pts leading, but if the button titles got long enough to where it would push the left button off the view, auto-layout would compress the button horizontally to keep `>= 10` points leading. But `>= 10` points leading by itself isn't enough information.

Comment: @user121095 - I edited my answer with additional explanation for clarity.